# Condition operators (< , >) do not work in gsl interpolation function

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, gsl

I have a question that seems very unusual to me. I have a condition statement that doesn't work as it should. Particularly, I have

```
double maxx = *max_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
if(x > maxx){
    cout << x << "\t" << maxx << endl;
    }
```

where `v1` is a vector. The weird thing is the output: it gives me equal numbers, i.g.

```
168.68 168.68
```

This statement is related to gsl interpolation function. In fact, it duplicates a statement in `interp.c:150` that causes an error of `gsl: interp.c:150: ERROR: interpolation error`. So when a number that should be executed normally comes to the function it actually gives `true` instead of `false` and I have no idea why, as the number (x) is actually equal to the maximal value allowed.

P.S.: I have checked the `if` statement on its own (with elementary entries) and it seems to work fine.

P.P.S.: A piece of code from `interp.c`:

```
double gsl_interp_eval (const gsl_interp * interp,
                const double xa[], const double ya[], double x,
                gsl_interp_accel * a){

 double y;

 int status;

 if (x < interp->xmin || x > interp->xmax)
   {
     GSL_ERROR_VAL("interpolation error", GSL_EDOM, GSL_NAN);
   }

 status = interp->type->eval (interp->state, xa, ya, interp->size, x, a, &y);

 DISCARD_STATUS(status);

 return y;}
```

So it returns an error even for `x = interp->xmax`, although it definitely should not.

UPDATE: I changed `double` to `long double` in declaration. This fixed some places (I use this function more than once), but not all of them.

Comment: I bet you anything those values are not equal.  Please try printing `(x - maxx)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like floating point inaccuracy. Try printing the values without limiting the number decimal places or printing `(x-maxx)` as suggested by Oli Charlesworth.

The usual solution to this kind of problem is to apply a small 'epsilon' on comparisons.

Comment: Thank you guys, you were absolutely right! It actually returned a very small difference. Shall I then rewrite the comparison in subtraction form or there is any more elegant way of solving this?

Comment: Given the maxx is hard limit, I don't see there is much you could do. I suppose you could cap values close to maxx, say < maxx + 0.0001 or something depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point is a tricky business, especially when comparing values. If the values are very close, they may well print the same, but still be different.

Have a look at:

http://floating-point-gui.de/